# No horizontal scrollbar in rails 4 bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

There is no horizontal scrollbar in my rails web app and the content falls out of page. I am using twitter bootstrap 3. I have no idea how to fix this.

Image
[image: IMG]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like `overflow: hidden` is in the CSS rule for body, html or any other wrapper element. Change it to `overflow: auto`

Comment: Which file should I modify? I can't seem to find it.